# Wiggle the blue value of the color in loopable expression - After Effects

Tags: javascript, function, after-effects

I have this loopable expression for After Effects:

```
seedRandom(1,true);
freq = 1.4;
amp = 1;
loopTime = 1;
t = time % loopTime;
wiggle1 = wiggle(freq, amp, 1, 0.5, t);
wiggle2 = wiggle(freq, amp, 1, 0.5, t - loopTime);
linear(t, 0,  loopTime, wiggle1, wiggle2)
```

This `amp = 1` randomizes the color completely (all rgb values). I need to wiggle just the blue value of the color instead. How to do it within this expression?

I know that I could add levels - individual controls effect and wiggle the blue value there, but in my specific case I need the expression for the blue value instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
seedRandom(1,true);
freq = 1.4;
amp = 1;
loopTime = 10;
t = time % loopTime;
wiggle1 = wiggle(freq, amp, 1, 0.5, t);
wiggle2 = wiggle(freq, amp, 1, 0.5, t - loopTime);
w = linear(t, 0, loopTime, wiggle1, wiggle2);
[value[0],value[1],w[2],value[3]];
```